# Dynamic Fields Remain Visible After refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible that an added dynamic fields will still visible after refresh.

I found a related topic but its complicated.
[related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712521/dynamic-fields-remain-when-error-occurs-upon-submission-or-refresh)

I want to implement it in my work.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/jqj1h4vb/

Thanks

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.voca:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.btn-add:not(:last)')
            .removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')

            .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove   ');
    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
    {
        $(this).parents('.voca:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">


        <div class="control-group" id="fields">
            <div class="controls"> 
                <form role="form" autocomplete="off">



                <div class="row">

                    <div class="voca">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name this snippet" name="voca" type="text" value="Dynamic Form Fields - Add & Remove BS3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name this snippet" name="vocatrans" type="text" value="Dynamic Form Fields - Add & Remove BS3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <select class="form-control">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add more
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>    

                </form>
            <br>

            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Dumisani, I believe OP is trying to _keep_ the fields after the page is refreshed

Comment: The related topic is kinda correct, you should wrap the code inside the onclick event and put it on its own function, then using cookies create a flag that checks if it's set on refresh, if it is then execute the function that adds the extra field

Comment: ok sir, I'll try that.

Comment: You just need to stored value in session, or in databse.

Comment: You can store your dynamic content in browser's `localStorage`.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm thinking of that too, but its hard for me to code that

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, the fields gets removed when the script is run again. I don't see the problem. And if the problem persist on your browser. Please use `Ctrl + F5` to refresh.

Comment: I believe OP is trying to _keep_ the fields after the page is refreshed

Comment: yes sir it was remove, what I want is if I generate fields it will remain visible

Answer (score 0):

**You can archive this by two ways ..**

1. Store value and data in session.
2. Store value and data in database.

And then after page load, you just fetch data from database or session